# Disable ReportViewer Page Navigation On Mouse Wheel

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a report that has a lot of data formatted to be printer friendly. On average there are 16 to 24 pages of data which my users can page through. I decided to make a windows forms `ReportViewer` (imported into WPF) and it works very well except for one thing: I cannot find how to disable the automatic page advance on scrolling.

I have looked through my rdlc report properties and the `ReportViewer` both and don't see any properties. I cannot find any information online either for it. is this not a feature that can be disabled or am I just not seeing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReportViewer` performs page navigation on mouse wheel by overriding `OnMouseWheel` method of an internal control named `ReportPanel`, so we can not override it, because it's internal.

`ReportViewer` control has a `PageNavigation` event which we can use it to cancel navigation. But we should distinguish if the event is raised by toolbar buttons or by mouse wheel. To do so, we handles `Click` event of toolbar buttons in code (and remove default event handler) and set a flag which will be used later to determine the navigation event is raised by toolbar.

I wrote a method which encapsulates the logic and makes disabling wheel navigation easy. To do so, it's enough to call the method this way:

```
DisableWheelNavigation(reportViewer1);
```

And here is the implementation of the method:

```
public void DisableWheelNavigation(ReportViewer r) {
    bool fromToolbar = false;
    r.PageNavigation += (obj, ea) => {
        if (fromToolbar) fromToolbar = false;
        else ea.Cancel = true;
    };
    var buttons = new string[] { "firstPage", "previousPage", "nextPage", "lastPage" };
    var toolstrip = r.Controls.Find("toolStrip1", true).OfType<ToolStrip>().First();
    toolstrip.Items.OfType<ToolStripButton>()
        .Where(button => buttons.Contains(button.Name)).ToList().ForEach(item => {
            var clickEvent = item.GetType().GetEvent("Click");
            var removeMethod = clickEvent.GetRemoveMethod();
            var d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(clickEvent.EventHandlerType,
                toolstrip.Parent, "OnPageNavButtonClick");
            removeMethod.Invoke(item, new object[] { d });
            item.Click += (obj, ev) => {
                var onPageNavigation = toolstrip.Parent.GetType()
                    .GetMethod("OnPageNavigation",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                Action<int> OnPageNavigation = i => {
                    fromToolbar = true;
                    onPageNavigation.Invoke(toolstrip.Parent, new object[] { i });
                };
                if (item.Name == "firstPage") OnPageNavigation(1);
                else if (item.Name == "previousPage") OnPageNavigation(r.CurrentPage - 1);
                else if (item.Name == "nextPage") OnPageNavigation(r.CurrentPage + 1);
                else if (item.Name == "lastPage") {
                    PageCountMode mode;
                    int totalPages = r.GetTotalPages(out mode);
                    if (mode != PageCountMode.Actual) OnPageNavigation(0x7fffffff);
                    else OnPageNavigation(totalPages);
                }
            };
        });
}
```